# Múltiplas chamadas para o webservice

Tags: c#, .net, web-service

Gostaria de saber a melhor forma para efetuar N chamadas para o mesmo Webservice.

Ex.: Em um sistema de busca / cotação de hotéis, como estratégia, utilizamos N chamadas para uma cotação em específico pois em cada chamada é enviado um Acordo Comercial diferente, em seguida é exibido o melhor preço baseado em todas as requisições de resposta.

No cenário atual, temos uma média de 20 requisições por cotação, porem fica muito lento devido uma chamada ser feita após a outra, sempre esperando o retorno para prosseguir.

Pensei em utilizar Threads para fazer todas as chamadas em paralelo e teoricamente o tempo total será mais ou menos o tempo de uma chamada, levando em consideração que todas serão disparadas no mesmo momento.

Gostaria de saber qual é a melhor forma de tratar esta situação, Thread seria a solução? Se sim, existe alguma estratégia para isto? Caso contrário, qual seria a melhor forma?